# c++ - duplicates of objects created in looped constructor call

Tags: c++, oop

I've defined a class and then create instances of it with a constructor in an array. For some reason this just creates instances, many of which just end up having exactly the same attributes, despite all of them being randomised. This is the constructor.

```
class fNNGA: public fNN
{
public:
    fNNGA()
    {

    }

    fNNGA(int n)
    {
        int i;

        _node.resize(n);

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            _node[i]._activation = -1;
        }
    }

    fNNGA(int n, int inp, int out, int edge)
    {
        int i,u,v;

        _node.resize(n);

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            _node[i]._activation = 1;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < inp; i++)
        {
            setInput(i);
        }

        for(i = n - out; i < n; i++)
        {
            setOutput(i);
        }

        for(i = 0; i < edge; i++)
        {
            v = rand() % (n - inp) + inp;
            u = rand() % v;

            setEdge(u,v);
        }

        init();
    }
};
```

And these are some of the ways I've been trying to get the array created:

```
fNNGA pop[SIZE];

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        pop[i] = fNNGA(100,16,8,800);
    }
}
```

,

```
fNNGA *pop[SIZE];

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        pop[i] = new fNNGA(100,16,8,800);
    }
}
```

,

```
fNNGA *pop = new fNNGA[SIZE];

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        new(pop[i]) fNNGA(100,16,8,800);
    }
}
```

How could I properly create these objects?

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `srand` in the constructor. Remember that on most platforms the `time` function returns the time in *seconds*, so if your constructor is called multiple times within one second (very likely to happen) then all those invocation will call `srand` and set the exact same seed.

Call `srand` *once* at the beginning of the program only. Or use the new [pseudo-random number generating classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) introduced in C++11.

Comment: I've moved srand() out of the constructor and into main, but the problem persists. Is any way I've tried to initialise the array correct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if your programs run in a second, you can't use `srand` for that all the results of `time(null)` is same. In addition, each time rand() is seeded with the same seed, it must produce the same sequence of values.

My test code and output is as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define null 0

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  srand(time(null));
  cout << "time:" << time(null) << endl;
  cout << "rand 0:" << rand() << " " << rand() << " " << rand() << endl << endl;

  //to make the program run for more than a second
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
  {
    int t = 0;
    t = t / 3;
    t = t / 3;
    t = t / 3;
    t = t / 3;
    t = t / 3;
    t = t / 3;
    t = t / 3;
  }

  srand(time(null));
  cout << "time:" << time(null) << endl;
  cout << "rand 1:" << rand() << " " << rand() << " " << rand() << endl << endl;

  srand(time(null));
  cout << "time:" << time(null) << endl;
  cout << "rand 2:" << rand() << " " << rand() << " " << rand() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

output:

> time:1452309501
>
> rand 0:5552 28070 20827
>
> time:1452309502
>
> rand 1:23416 6051 20830
>
> time:1452309502
>
> rand 2:23416 6051 20830

More details information, ref to [srand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) , [time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time)

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with srand(). I could just take the srand() out and it still behaves the same way.

Comment: I have test your code on my PC, it generate randomize value normally after you removed `srand`. I do not known what you have done with `setEdge(u,v)`, maybe you can check it.

Comment: Does the fact that the class is actually defined in a separate file change the outcome?